# Django: object not iterable

Tags: python, django

I want to fill my model form with initial data. However, I always receive an `'Attendee' object is not iterable`. Full traceback: http://dpaste.com/0BH9MAM

When I comment this out: `initial=self.object,` the error disappears. However, my from is not pre-filled with any data. As I add more forms I can't work with `FormMixin` or `UpdateForm`

```
class AssignAttendee(SuccessMessageMixin, SingleObjectMixin, TemplateView):
        template_name = 'attendees/front/assign_attendee.html'
        success_message = _("Attendee has been successfully updated.")

        def get_object(self):
            return get_object_or_404(
                Attendee,
            ticket_reference=self.kwargs['ticket_reference'],
            ticket_code=self.kwargs['ticket_code'],
        )

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #     self.object = self.get_object()
    #     return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    @cached_property
    def attendee_form(self):
        return AssignAttendeeForm(
            prefix='attendee',
            data=self.request.POST or None,
            initial=self.object,
        )

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context = {
            'attendee': self.object,
            'attendee_form': self.attendee_form,
        }
        return context
```

**forms.py**

```
class AssignAttendeeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Attendee
        fields = (
            'ticket_reference',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'company_name',
            'email',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['ticket_reference'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.fields['ticket_reference'].disabled = True
        for visible_field in self.visible_fields():
            visible_field.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a dict to [`Form.initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial), not an object.

You are probably looking for the [`ModelForm.instance`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values) keyword argument, which allows updating an existing instance of a model.